# Set default branch (or revision) to diff against, in magit

Tags: magit

I frequently diff against the "master" branch, and would like it to be easier in magit.

Right now, I can do one of these:

- `y`, then scroll to `master`, then hit `d d RET`.
- `l l`, then scroll to the commit, then `d r RET`
- `d r master RET`
- maybe other ways

What I'd like is something simpler, where I can hit say `d m` and it would show the diff against `master` (or even better, against the result of `git merge-base master HEAD`). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> or even better, against the result of `git merge-base master HEAD`

That would be `master...HEAD` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251477/what-are-the-differences-between-double-dot-and-triple-dot-in-git-dif).

> Actually what I think I want is the diff between that "common ancestor" commit, and the current working tree (or staging area) rather than the committed HEAD.

For that you can use `magit-diff-working-tree` (or `magit-diff-staged`) with `magit-git-string` to get the merge-base.

```el
(defun magit-diff-master (&optional args)
  "Show diff range master...HEAD"
  (interactive (list (magit-diff-arguments)))
  (magit-diff "master...HEAD" args))

(defun magit-diff-mbase (&optional args)
  "Show diff of $(git merge-base master HEAD) to working tree."
  (interactive (list (magit-diff-arguments)))
  (magit-diff-working-tree
   (magit-git-string "merge-base" "master" "HEAD") args))

(magit-define-popup-action 'magit-diff-popup
  ?m "Diff merge-base master" 'magit-diff-mbase)
```

Comment: I believe `git diff master...HEAD` and `git diff $(git merge-base master HEAD)..HEAD` should be the same? Anyway I'll give this a try and ping here again, thanks for answering.

Comment: This seems to work; thank you so much! I'll test it for a day or two and mark this as accepted. Thanks for showing me `magit-define-popup-action`; now I know how to achieve a lot of things.

Comment: Actually what I think I want is the diff between that "common ancestor" commit, and the current working tree (or staging area) rather than the committed HEAD. It looks like I can achieve this by calling `magit-diff` with just one commit as argument, where that commit is the output of `git merge-base master HEAD`. (There may also be other ways.) Might you have any idea how to get this commit inside magit?

Comment: Yes, you can also use `magit-diff-working-tree` which makes your intent clearer (of course it just calls `magit-diff`); see updated answer.

Comment: I am now using `(defun magit-diff-develop (&optional args)
  "Show diff range develop...HEAD"
  (interactive)
  (magit-diff "develop" args))
(global-set-key "\C-cd" 'magit-diff-develop)` To show me the diff from our base branch `develop` to my working tree, which I find useful.  We deploy `master`.

Comment: With never magit versions, [Transient](https://magit.vc/manual/transient.html) is now used. Instead of `magit-define-popup-action`, something like `(transient-append-suffix 'magit-diff "w" '("m" "Diff merge-base master" magit-diff-mbase))` is needed (where `"w"` is the existing action after which the new one will be placed).

Comment: The last comment doesn't seem to work `magit-diff is not a transient command`